# Using Singleton Class

Tags: iphone, ios

I have made use of a delegates in the past to share information about an Object (with it's associated properties) across different classes, but I'm planning a new App and thinking of using a Singleton Class to do this.

Is it mandatory protocol to use delegates to share information between classes, or can I simply employ a Singleton Class ?

Looking forward to some views or good advise on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to share information between controllers. It solely depends upon your design what you opt to choose. Usually **singletons** are used to store information globally to be used by whole app anywhere. For example, to store game's score and its another stuff. **Delegate** is used to communicate between limited number of controllers. BTW you can broadcast your data to all "listening" controllers via **Notifications**. So again it really depends upon your design that what should you choose.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question for clarity, but thank you for comments. Will probably go ahead and use a Single Class.

Answer (score 5):

You may be missing the basic point of Model-View-Controller, which is the primary pattern of Cocoa apps. Under MVC, there is no reason to "share information across…Tableview Controllers." There is a model layer. The model layer hold all the data. The view layer (including tableviews) reads the model layer and displays it. Views objects don't need to talk to each other very much. They mostly update the model and then read from the model.

You can implement the model as a singleton, or as an object that is passed into the view controllers when they are initialized. Both approaches have advantages. But there's no need for your view controllers to talk to each other in any case.

Comment: Apologies, I phrased the question poorly, see edited question.

Comment: Appreciated you comments

Answer (score 0):

You do have several options.  Core data, singleton, some sort of shared memory (maybe your pointer is in the Navigation Controller so you can share it with multiple screens -- or maybe in your AppDelegate), delegates, etc.

Comment: I have re-phrased the question for clarity.

Comment: Yes, the Singleton Class would be placed in the AppDelegate, seems to work ok for me.